# How to get count of files listed under specific directory from docker?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I have created one container and there are so many directories are there. And, I also get the files listed under the directory using `docker exe <container_name> ls <specific_dir_path>` command. But, I want to get count of that listed files under the directory.

Comment: A quick and easy solution is to pipe the result to `wc -l`.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean that you want *only* a count of the files?

Comment: to get the total file in all sub directories and all directories `docker exec -i <my_container>  sh -c 'echo total_File=$(find /root -type f -follow -print | wc -l) && echo total_directory=$(find /root -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l)'
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker exec -it <container_name> ls -rt1 <specific_dir_path> | wc -l` will output to your host shell a count of files and directories.

For example, in a container I have 11 directories:

```sh
 $ docker exec -it ac50a257f93b ls
bin   dev   etc   home  proc  root  sys   tmp   usr   var   www
```

So if I run this command to count them, it shows `11`:

```sh
$ docker exec -it ac50a257f93b ls -rt1 | wc -l
11
```

Comment: Thanks for the help [Brian Dant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785400/brian-dant). This docker command **docker exec -it <container_name> ls -rt1 | wc -l** works for me.